# What is a good free interface to create and store positions?

Tags: tactics, checkmate

I'm getting back into chess, and I'd like a way to create and store multiple chess positions to review. Specifically, I want to review and practice mating nets. There are a ton of chess tactics sites that offer tactics training, but I want to be able to create and review specific types of positions. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: On Chessable you can create your own private course and input whatever you want in there and review it. Downside: Requires internet connection to run.

Comment: @B.Swan Another downside to chessable is it's not a "good" interface.  It is pretty buggy and looks like it was designed circa the mid-1990s.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PGN file of those position you could use [my site](https://listudy.org/en) for that. There are already a couple of people using the site not to study openings but have uploaded PGNs of endgame positions to train.

If your PGN software specifies a starting position not inside of a "FEN" header let me know: https://github.com/ArneVogel/listudy/issues/2